# Копировать поля объекта базового класса в поля производного

Tags: c#

```
class Ancestor 
{
  string field1 {get;set;}
  string field2 {get;set;}
  SomeClass field3 {get;set;}
  //...
}

class Descendent : Ancestor
{
  string field4 {get;set;}
}
```

Есть базовый класс (Ancestor) с множеством полей. некоторые поля ссылочного типа (т.е. тоже классы). Можно ли поля объекта базового класса копировать в объект производного (Descendent) класса не перебирая каждое отдельное поле? Т.е. без такого -

```
descendent.field1 = ancestor.field1;
descendent.field2 = ancestor.field2;
```

Полей много, поэтому такое решение не подходит

Пробовал делать так:

```
descendent = ancestor as Descendent;
```

В результате `descendent == null`

**Из комментариев:** Задача такая. Нужно из метода возвращать объекты базового класса + 1 поле, в котором будет хранится текст (ссылка на картинку). Базовый класс менять не могу. Поэтому сделал производный Descendent

Comment: зачем? что вы вообще пытаетесь сделать? какую задачу? Наследование не решает её?

Comment: Задача такая. Нужно из метода возвращать объекты базового класса + 1 поле, в котором будет хранится текст (ссылка на картинку). Базовый класс менять не могу. Поэтому сделал производный                        class Descendent : Ancestor который дополнил одним полем типа string  и попытался сделать то, что в описании вопроса

Comment: @Дмитрий у Вас не получается объяснить словами, что Вы делаете. Добавляйте в вопрос больше кода.

Comment: @Дмитрий уже лучше. Как создаются эти объекты?

Comment: Объекты базового класса создаются выборкой из списка linq запросом по наличию одного из bool полей c флагом true. Дальше объекты нужно передать в представление + передать строку с текстом ссылки на картинку для каждого.

Comment: Только для этого? Что вам мешает сделать новую сущность со свойствами `Ancestor` и ссылкой на картинку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте новый агрегатный класс и передавайте в представление набор объектов этого типа.

```
public class Aggregate
{
  public Ancestor Data { get; set; }
  string field4 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Нельзя.

1. Но можно сделать конструктор или статический метод, который будет это делать поштучно. В таком случае перебрать все поля предётся только в одном месте.
2. Можно сделать рефлексией, но это будет работать очень медленно.
3. Можно рефлексией выбрать поля и в рантайме скомпилировать код, который будет их копировать. Или воспользоваться каким-нибудь mapper'ом, который так и делает.
4. Можно при компиляции сгенерировать код при помощи расширения для VS.